# Solution for Validation Accuracy Higher Than Training Accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am training from a transfer learning model of CNN in Pytorch, but in every epoch its validation accuracy is higher than training accuracy.

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ruQv.png)

I am not sure whether this accuracy would cause a problem or not.
and I would like to have some suggestions to improve the validation accuracy.
e.g. Should I ignore the thenomenon or I should fix it?
Also, how should I evaluate the performance (e.g. overfitting/underfitting)?

I looked for other question asking about why this will happen and found a lot of explanations about the reason.
However, there is still not much good answers on the corresponding treatment.

1. Caused by Dropout layers.

   However, even I turned on eval mode in Pytorch, the problem still happens.
2. Dataset Augmentation

   I indeed used augmentation, but I only applied very basic augmentation such as horizontal flip.
   So I wonder whether this will still be the main cause.
3. Underfitting

   I am not sure about this.

Comment: Common is the problem that your traning accuracy is higher (sign of Overfitting). Depending on the setup like droupout, augmentation etc. which makes the training harder yields training accuracy that might be less good. But because of the harder training it can now perform better on real/validation data -> higher accuracy compared to test data.
So this is nothing you want to fix but actually reach. As long as the accuracy is high, if it were low then it would be an underfitting.

Comment: As @Daraan says, it is not a "bug to fix" even if you should find a good trade-off between more and less regularization (check limit validation performance only)! Now if you still have the phenomenon by removing dropout and data augmentation, it can because you have data shifting: distribution of validation set is simpler to predict than distribution of train set